# Sugarcrm - custom fields label text is not showing in administration module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have been developing a module for Sugarcrm and the issue is that while the fields themsleves show up in the config panel they only show the label variable names and not the actual text.

```
$mod_strings = array(
'LBL_MODULE_MANAGEMENT_TITLE' => 'Company text', //rest of code omitted
```

So in my case "LBL_MODULE_MANAGEMENT_TITLE" is showing up instead of "Company text". What could possibly be the problem?

/Erik

Comment: I think you have to add it in perticular language file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a concurrent languagefile in custom/modules/ModuleX/language/en_us.lang.php.

Please specify the path where your languagefile is located.

Comment: \custom\Extension\modules\Administration\Ext\Language\

Comment: oy thats the right place where it should be. But do you have another file in custom/modules/Administration/language/ ? tis would override all the others if I remember correctly.